# Bounded context and involvement of Domain expert

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

While we are deducing the bounded context , do the domain expert should or must understand the terms like "bounded context" , "problem space" , "sub-domain". Or even, what constitutes a bounded context or a sub-domain ?

For example , while creating Clinic system domain, the sub domains would be appointment system , patient management. So the question is should I tell my domain expert that I am a developer and I am dividing the problem into smaller sub-domains and a boundary context ( appointment system) would constitute patients and billing contexts. and the "context map" here are blah blah.

Essentially, should the domain expert care about I am following the DDD approach or CRUD approach of development or in other words should the terms "bounded context","sub-domain" etc should be included in the Ubiquitous language ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain experts should know about the problem space, but they shouldn't *have to* know about the solution space.

Domains and subdomains describe the problem space. I can't think of a way to talk with experts about the different parts of a business without giving a generic name to these parts. Subdomains is the word we have in DDD, why not use it ? Subdomains also often match different teams or divisions in a company and that's surely something that will come up in the discussions with the expert.

In sentences like

> - This team handles the Invoicing [...]
> - Okay, now we're done with the Purchase [...], let's move on to the Stock [...]
> - Doesn't this feature rather belong to the Appointment [...] ?

you will need some concept to fill in the blanks.

Bounded Contexts, in contrast, are in the solution space. I can see why you would talk in these terms to a QA person or maybe a CTO, but not to a business expert. It's the same as mentioning a database, a web server or a message queue. The expert will want to know more if they are curious, but you shouldn't base your conversations on them understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

"DDD language" is the Ubiquitous Language from the DDD book, NOT the developers' metadata-jargon.

Eric Evans is pretty clear on this topic. Chapter 2, paragraph "Ubuquitous language":

> Domain experts should object to terms or structures that are awkward
>   or inadequate to convey domain understanding; developers should watch
>   for ambiguity or inconsistency that will trip up design.

Look at a diagram in "One team, one language" paragraph in the same chapter to see WHAT is UL. It includes "names of Bounded Contexts" (that is, `"Appointment system"` and `"Patient management"` in your example), but not the term `"Bounded Context"`.

Domain expert has other important things to do with her brain cells than learning our jargon. In fact, her job is so complex that you're developing a system to automate it.

Have mercy and say `"Appointment system"` instead of `"sub-domain"`, or `"In <specific case> the Order moves from Appointment system to Patient management department"` instead of `"This Order is an interface point on a cross-domain boundary"`. This will help both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you SHOULD share the bounded contexts and sub domains with the domain expert. The idea behind DDD is shared and agreed knowledge.

However, I don't think you have to use the precise terms 'bounded context' and 'sub domain'. You could use those and these could be in the ubiquitous language - if helpful. I think that is a question as to how well your domain expert will understand these terms, of if you ought to use different terms to make it easy for them to follow.

Comment: I was thinking the same, which I did and said to my Domain expert. Saying " I realized that I cant have this information in this bounded context, so I am moving it into the other bounded context. Essentially the contact info for appointment is not good in this context I am moving it into the visitor bounded context", His answer was," Well,hmm. ahhm, I still can be able to book an appointment right ?"

Comment: Ha!.. Yes, tricky. Do they understand the bounded contexts? Perhaps you need to spend more time refining those with them - or, if they are unhelpful, then simplify them or do away with them.

Comment: They do comprehend it, but they seem uninterested. I found it does not interest them as they say perhaps :). "You have your ugly Momma, you love her. But don't expect me to kiss her".

Answer (score 1):

#### Ubiquitous Language

In my understanding, the Ubiquitous Language (UL) is a set of very powerful linguistic tools to collaborate effectively with the problem domain experts. I would image the UL as language proxy or translator service between the developers and the domain experts. Therefore, the UL should not contain any programming related technology terminologies, but domain concepts.

To give you an example when the developer thinks about a domain concept:

> When handling the command `PatientRequiresAppointment` in the `Appointment` module, the `AppointmentDomainService` should make a check that the `Patient`'s SSN-id is valid and has been paid for, based on the incoming DTO properties.

If we try to translate this to a more domain-friendly language:

> Appointment entries get confirmed when the Patient's social insurance number is checked and confirmed for validity.

Now this version is cleared out of technological jargon, but it may introduce two unknown verbs. Checking and confirming those should be coordinated with the domain expert. In this way, the UL of your domain will be reshaped constantly, and will get new verbs/nouns introduced or removed for instance when you notice that you have been using some kind of overloaded terms (ex.: AppointmentDomainService in the first example).

By now you could get the importance of the spoken UL, the next thing to answer is:

#### Should you use DDD terminology with your domain experts?

One of the key concepts of DDD is *collaboration!* So yes, you should work closely with your domain experts by even teaching them the insights of a so-called bounded context. I believe that this is an added value to the team in the long run, because they will also learn what the boundaries of a given context are, and you will also learn how that area of the problem domain really works in their business.

#### Epilogue: some of the other values DDD might bring to your team

I will try to explain some of the success I have gained by applying DDD on focused parts of a project.

- Clear and precise boundaries of the context: the things in the above sections applied in the flow of your team *might* result in clean and pure domain models, focused on the actual domain context with strictly defined boundaries to help bring the focused *solution* to the given business problem! In general terms, this might mean clean and pure code aiming for easier testing which might introduce less bugs and faster delivery times. This list could be continued endlessly...
- Being agile: one of the greatest benefits of DDD to me was to learn how I could be more *agile.* Agility in this context might mean, for instance, that you can learn how to balance carefully when modeling a business problem, which you may iteratively refine by working closely with your domain experts. I have also learned how to be more agile by continuously delivering new features. This might indicate that you can also learn new ways to be more agile when contracting with your business partner by convincing them with these added values.

Comment: From my experience below comment to @benjaminhull, I realized almost all of the domain expert care about and help you understand what problems they are facing. But uninterested in how I solve them. They do care in terms of "I should be able to do it"," I have a huge user base,so my application should not be down", as I explain them I am going to have my team divided in developing each bounded context and can work faster. All I get it "yeah okay good to know", and to that "Then , perhaps I expect an early delivery" followed by some sarcastic smile.

Comment: can you give me an example how can I be sure that convincing them of knowing my "boundary context"  help our product to be better, and the solution space ( boundary context ) is something they should also be interested in.

Comment: this is one of the reasons why DDD is still alive and kicking. But still your Epilogue do not answer my problem. I found solution space at most has nothing to do with Domain Experts

Comment: I'm not sure. In an ideal world the solution space is how the models realize a solution of the problem space. In the end solution space is the software you craft... however real life works differently than we read in books, I fear that there is no _exact_ solution how could you work yourself through that problem with your human team members... but in the end that could turn this whole Q&A to something that's not closely programming related :)